# Landscape - Servers with 22.04 cannot finish activities

Tags: server, 22.04, cloud, landscape

We are using Landscape (cloud based) and have around 35 servers connected to it. Most of them are 18.04, but we are now migrating those servers to 22.04. So some of them are 22.04 now.

All servers report to Landscape as supposed to (package updates, reboots, etc). But when Landscape starts an activity based on such a report, that activity gets stuck on 22.04 servers, but it works just fine at 18.04 servers.

Does anyone has a clue what is happening and point me in the right direction here?